# Помогите с заданием по Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать код. Где входные данные должны прочитываться из текстового файла. Результат работы программы должен записываться в другой файл, а не выводиться на экран.

---

Пусть дана произвольная строка. Удалите первые 2 символа этой строки и добавьте 2 новых символа в конец. Новые символы должны вводиться пользователем с клавиатуры.

---

```
urstr = input("Введите ваш текст: ")
urstr = urstr[:0] + urstr[2:] + input("Добавьте 2 новых символа: ")
print(urstr)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - "...Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. .."

Comment: покажите пожалуйста код, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
urstr = input("Введите ваш текст: ")

urstr = urstr[2:] + input("Добавьте 2 новых символа: ")

#print(urstr)

#  печатать прямо в файл 'filename.txt' 
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(urstr, file=f)
```

---

**Update**

```
#urstr = input("Введите ваш текст: ")
#  читаем входные данныеиз файла 'filename_in.txt' 
with open('filename_in.txt', 'r') as f:
    urstr = f.read()
    print(urstr)

urstr = urstr[2:] + input("Добавьте 2 новых символа: ")

#print(urstr)

#  печатать прямо в файл 'filename_out.txt' 
with open('filename_out.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(urstr, file=f)
```

**filename_in.txt**

```
123456789
```

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы входные данные прочитывались из текстового файла?

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы хоть показали попытки... Код то совсем основы...

```
txt = "MyText"
a = txt.removeprefix(txt[:2])
f = input("текст:")
l = a + f[:2] 
print(l)
```